# Modal truncated upon load

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I'm facing a rare issue with the modal I made. I had a iframe to load a embedded youtube video on the modal, it was working well on a separate HTML file (an empty) that I had created to test it.

When I tried loading it on a local template of the actual site the youtube video is truncated. And, when i press ctrl+shift+i (the console) the whole video comes out. I searched for any possible solution to the issue.

Can anyone help me. Attaching the photo beneath.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I somehow fixed this issue.

**Issues Faced:-**

1) I noticed that the truncated video becomes full-sized when I pull up the console log (crtl+shift+i)

2)I tried reloading the div content using innerHTML

3)I tried applying min-height property, the div comes out in the full size but the video still remains the same.

**How I fixed it:-**

I removed the src from the iframe and then on the function to show the modal i added a line to set the iframes source. This somehow fixed my issue.

Addntly, I also removed all the previous changes made to the CSS and JS file, as listed above.

*I know both the question and the solution sounds weird (It does to me too)*